# Is there a way to verify if a Windows registry key is volatile (REG_OPTION_VOLATILE)?

Tags: registry, volatile

In Windows registry the keys can  be created as volatile - meaning that a volatile key is not going to survive a PC reboot. After the reboot no trace of such key will be found in registry.
This is specified by the option REG_OPTION_VOLATILE of API RegCreateKeyEx.

I need to verify if a certain Windows registry key is volatile or not (created with REG_OPTION_VOLATILE).

For example, the key may be located under (HKLM\Software\MyCompany\MyProgram\KeyToBeChecked).

There seem to be no direct WIN API-s that allow making this sort of check.

Does anyone know how this could be checked?

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense - what do you mean by 'volatile'?  Do you mean, whether the key can be written to?

Comment: Just updated question, to better describe the volatile keys.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to try creating a non-volatile subkey under the key that's being verified, using `RegCreateKeyEx`. If the key is indeed volatile, then it would fail with error `ERROR_CHILD_MUST_BE_VOLATILE`. Even `ShSetValue` returns `ERROR_CHILD_MUST_BE_VOLATILE` while trying to set a value in a volatile key.

Comment: +1. You can use a simple reg.exe command to create a subkey under the volatile one as a test and it will error.  E.g.

`reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\volkeytocheck\test`

"ERROR: Cannot create a stable subkey under a volatile parent key."

If you check with Process Monitor, Reg.exe will get the result for the RegCreateKey operation listed as "CHILD MUST BE VOLATILE".

Comment: Might fail ACCESS_DENIED!  Where would that leave you?

Answer (score 3):

begin from win7 exist undocumented way - need call [`ZwQueryKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-zwquerykey) with [`KeyFlagsInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ne-wdm-_key_information_class). with this we can query are key volatile or not, also - are key is symbolic link to another key. code can look like:

```
struct KEY_CONTROL_FLAGS_INFO_W7  // KeyFlagsInformation for Win7
{
    ULONG ControlFlags[3];
};

#define KEY_CTRL_FL_W7_01__IS_VOLATILE                                 0x01
#define KEY_CTRL_FL_W7_01__SYM_LINK                                    0x02


    HKEY hKey;
    LSTATUS r = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 
        L"Volatile Environment", REG_OPTION_OPEN_LINK, KEY_READ, &hKey);
    if (r == NOERROR)
    {
        ULONG cb;
        KEY_CONTROL_FLAGS_INFO_W7 kcf;

        if (0 <= ZwQueryKey(hKey, KeyFlagsInformation, &kcf, sizeof(kcf), &cb))
        {
            if (kcf.ControlFlags[1] & KEY_CTRL_FL_W7_01__IS_VOLATILE)
            {
                DbgPrint("key is volatile\n");
            }

            if (kcf.ControlFlags[1] & KEY_CTRL_FL_W7_01__SYM_LINK)
            {
                DbgPrint("key is link\n");
            }
        }
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }
```

Comment: @eryksun - this flags found not i. and i don't know how/from where this was. despite here [`KEY_FLAGS_INFORMATION`](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntregapi.h#L83) defined as single `DWORD` if call `ZwQueryKey(..KeyFlagsInformation..)` we can view that output size is `0xc` - so must be 3 `DWORD`. [here](https://github.com/rbmm/NtRegView/tree/master/research) already my registry scan for flags. i found several else one flags on some keys, but i can not interpret it - what is it mean. may be you can/know this.