# Get non-volatile registry key

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I need to get non-volatile registry keys, I fount [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432977/is-there-a-way-to-verify-if-a-windows-registry-key-is-volatile-reg-option-volat), but the proposed solution seems incorrect.
I also tried to open registry key with REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE option like this:

```
HKEY hKey;
LSTATUS result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"HARDWARE", 
                              REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_READ, &hKey);
```

The `result` stores `ERROR_SUCCESS` although as I know `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE` is volatile.
So my question is how can I figure out if key volatile or not?

The answer in [the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432977/is-there-a-way-to-verify-if-a-windows-registry-key-is-volatile-reg-option-volat) resolve problem at driver level. I need solution in user space.

Comment: `REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE` is not documented as an option to `RegOpenKeyEx`https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I need to do this because of transfer linux application, that uses hivex library. The interface must be the same. When linux is running, it can access only volatile hives

Comment: are you try check is key volatile ? or what ?

Comment: and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE` **not** volatile

Comment: can look for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50877967/6401656)

Comment: *The answer in the topic resolve problem at driver level. I need solution in user space.* - this is false. this is **user mode** solution too

Comment: So why is [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-zwquerykey) placed at wdm section?

Comment: If this is user mode, how can I use it in my app?

Comment: @АлександрЩетнев - and so what ? are you dont know that all Zw/Nt api available from user mode ? exported by ntdll

Comment: @АлександрЩетнев - very simply - link with `ntdll.lib` and use. can i ask - how you can call `RegOpenKeyEx` for example ?