# Checking if registry key is link to (or copy of) another one

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

How can I check out if registry key is link to another one using winapi?

For example, I need to find out which branch is original `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY\SAM` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM`, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` or `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21`.

I'm confused with types of keys and values. Does key have type? Can I use `REG_LINK` type for this purpose?

Comment: exist [undocumented way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50877967/6401656) todo this begin from win7, if this ok for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all we must open the key itself, rather than the key that the potential symbolic link key refers to (which is the default behavior).

For this we need to use `REG_OPTION_OPEN_LINK` option in call [`RegOpenKeyExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopenkeyexw) or [`ZwOpenKeyEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-zwopenkeyex).
An alternative way is to use `OBJ_OPENLINK` attribute in [`OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wudfwdm/ns-wudfwdm-_object_attributes). and use this in call `ZwOpenKey[Ex]`

After the key is opened we can query (starting from win7) undocumented [`KeyFlagsInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ne-wdm-_key_information_class) information via `ZwQueryKey`. If the flags shows that this is symbolic link - we can query `SymbolicLinkValue` value to get the link target key. Note that even if this value exists with type `REG_LINK` - this doesn't prove that this is symbolic link.

```
struct KEY_CONTROL_FLAGS_INFO_W7  // KeyFlagsInformation for Win7
{
    ULONG ControlFlags[3];
};

#define KEY_CTRL_FL_W7_01__IS_VOLATILE                                 0x01
#define KEY_CTRL_FL_W7_01__SYM_LINK                                    0x02

LSTATUS IsSymLink(HKEY hKey, PCWSTR lpSubKey, BOOL& IsLink)
{
    LSTATUS r = RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, lpSubKey, REG_OPTION_OPEN_LINK, KEY_READ|KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hKey);

    if (r == NOERROR)
    {
        ULONG Type, cb = 0, rcb = 0x80;

        KEY_CONTROL_FLAGS_INFO_W7 kcf;

        NTSTATUS status;

        if (0 <= (status = ZwQueryKey(hKey, KeyFlagsInformation, &kcf, sizeof(kcf), &cb)))
        {
            if (kcf.ControlFlags[1] & KEY_CTRL_FL_W7_01__SYM_LINK)
            {
                IsLink = TRUE;
                DbgPrint("key is link\n");

                PVOID stack = alloca(guz), buf = 0;

                do 
                {
                    if (cb < rcb)
                    {
                        cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
                    }

                    r = RegQueryValueExW(hKey, L"SymbolicLinkValue", 0, &Type, (PBYTE)buf, &(rcb = cb));

                    if (r == NOERROR && Type == REG_LINK && !(rcb & (sizeof(WCHAR) - 1)))
                    {
                        DbgPrint("%.*S\n", rcb / sizeof(WCHAR), buf);
                    }

                } while (r == ERROR_MORE_DATA);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            r = RtlNtStatusToDosError(status);
        }

        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }

    return r;
}
```

---

> Does key have type?

No. type have values of key only

> Can I use REG_LINK type for this purpose?

We can on a regular(not link) key create `SymbolicLinkValue` value with type `REG_LINK`, but key doesn't become a link after this. Key must be initially created with [`REG_OPTION_CREATE_LINK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regcreatekeyexw) option. So by querying `SymbolicLinkValue` value we can't reliably check if this is a link, but if we know that this is a link - we can get the target of the link by querying `SymbolicLinkValue`